# Spring security custom login form action vs default-target-url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, security, spring-security

When creating a spring-security application with custom login form, we need to specify `default-target-url` in `<http>` tag. This represents the REST API endpoint which should get called in case of successful authentication and authorization.

In custom login form, we have an action attribute. Should this action be same as `default-target-url`? Should there be a REST API endpoint configured for this action in my controller? Or will spring handle it internally and then forward the request to `default-target-url` after initially handling it itself?

I know this looks like a very basic question but I haven't found explanation for this in any online tutorial or even Spring's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I figured out that the `action` and `login-processing-url` both attributes should point to same endpoint `login`. This activates in-built filter in spring responsible for handling authentication. After successful authentication, we land on the endpoint specified by `default-target-url`.

Answer (score 1):

default-target-url is where you should land the user **after** successful authentication and authorization.

The action attribute in custom login form is the regular action attribute on form submit, not specific to spring security custom login form.

So, when you specify action attribute in the custom login form, you are specifying the request mapping method to be invoked in case of the login form **POST** - which is the user submit after specifying the login credentials.

This is the place where you will handle the authentication and authorization, and if successful, user will be landed on either the default-target-url or the login success page that you return from the request mapping. Of course, if invalid credentials are supplied, you redirect to login page with appropriate error messages.

Comment: What if I have provided the authentication and authorization details in the spring security config itself? What should action point to in this case, since authentcation and authorization will be handled by spring internally?

Comment: In that case, it should be action="j_spring_security_check", for Spring to take charge as per the configurations.

Comment: "j_spring_security_check" did not work for me. I figured out that action attribute should be same as login-processing-url attribute in <form-login> tag.